# Find a density function for the endpoint of this stochastic process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$(X_t, Y_t, Z_t)$ is a three-dimensional stochastic process described as follows:

$X_t$ is a Brownian Motion.

$Y_t = \int_0^t X_s ds$

$Z_t = \inf_{s \in [0, t]} X_s$

I would like to find a density function for the value of the process at time $t_f$.  Can this be done, despite the fact that $Z_t$ makes the process non-Markov?

Helpful information: the transition density function for $(X_t, Y_t)$ is well known.  See the intro to [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.17.8220%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=YXjqUOavLemu2QWq1YGYDg&usg=AFQjCNFxDyAvqgOA7gCPKHSMxYxfN-U1IQ&sig2=UjNlLmnF47LktJ06qNe-lQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.b2I).  The challenge is adding $Z_t$ into the mix.

Comment: What is $t_f$? Also your link seems to be wrong - i'm getting: No document with DOI "10.1.1.17.8220".

Comment: $t_f$ is some positive constant - for generality, I'm leaving it variable.  And link fixed (I think), thank you.

Comment: Anyway, $(X_t,Y_t,Z_t)$ is distributed like $(\sqrt{t}X_1,t\sqrt{t}Y_1,\sqrt{t}Z_1)$ hence the case $t=1$ suffices.